# How do I substitute one entry for another an MS Access report?

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I recently started working with MS Access 2010, and I am trying to generate labels from a form that I have created. In the form, three pieces of information are put in by the user: style, color code, and unit of measure (UoM). The style numbers appear the same way on the form and in the report, and I have been able to get that to work.

However, for the color code, I need both the inputted color code and the actual color to show up on the report. I have a table that has all of the color codes with the corresponding color names. I cannot figure out how to get the text box that is supposed to show the color name to show it. I know virtually no SQL, but I found information on it on the internet and pieced together this code in the ControlSource for the text box the color name is supposed to be in:

```
=(SELECT [Description]
FROM [Color]
WHERE([Forms]![Box Label Form]![ThirdJoined]=[Color]![ColorCode]))
```

[Description] is the name of the column within the [Color] table that gives the actual color name.

[Box Label Form] is the name of the form.

[ThirdJoined] is the name of the input text box within the form.

[ColorCode] is the name of the column within the [Color] table that gives that color code.

This code doesn't work, and only results in #NAME appearing in Print Preview view. How can I get this to work, either code-wise or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the `ControlSource` of a textbox to a SQL statement. You could set it to a DLOOKUP function to lookup a single value. You also need to separate out the reference to the form control using concatenation (&).

```
=DLOOKUP("Description","[Color]","ColorCode='"&[Forms]![Box Label Form]![ThirdJoined]&"'")
```

I'm assuming the Color is a text-value so the form-value needs to be enclosed in apostrophes.

If this expression is used on the form [Box Label Form] then you don't need to qualify the name of the Control:

```
=DLOOKUP("Description","[Color]","ColorCode='"&[ThirdJoined]&"'")
```

Comment: I tried the first thing of code and it told me that I was missing an ending parenthesis, bracket, or vertical bar. When I put a parenthesis at the end of it, it didn't give me that error message, but when I tried Print Preview, it gave me #Error.

Comment: I've corrected my answer as the bracket needs to be after the closing quote. But you should be studying this rather than just copying and pasting it.